# Difference in import mechanism

Tags: python, import

While importing a module from the same package, sometimes I try

```
from .module import *
```

But I really don't get how is it different from

```
from module import *
```

Are both of them relative import? Which one should be preferred?

Comment: The first one. Don't use the second one; it will not even work with Python 3. (At least not for relative imports.)

Comment: @Evert But isn't using `.` is also relative?

Comment: And as to, why not use the second one for relative imports? What if there's another module in `site-packages` that is called the same (i.e., `module`): you can't import that module, because you'd be importing the local one instead.

Comment: You asked which one is preferred: the first one. They're both relative *only* in Python 2; in Python 3, only the first one is relative. Hence stick the first one.

Comment: Other note: don't use `import *`. Ever. Keep some kind of namespacing around. `import *` will bite you, and probably sooner than later.

Comment: As a matter of fact: absolute imports (also in packages) are preferred (but not mandated). Read this [section on imports in PEP 8](https://www.python.org/dev/peps/pep-0008/#imports).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As pointed by Evert in comments,

The second one should *not* be preferred. That won't work in python 3. So, using `from .module import name` is beneficial.

And so as, `import *` should never be used. That's a bad practice.